# Need logging system software

Tags: log-files, logging, remote

I have a N-Tier system for our clients to access data, and we're finding that our current logging system (built into the server application) is insufficient for storing all the data we need.  Now, I need to find a new solution for saving and storing logs, and was looking at two different options that I could find: using a remote syslog setup, and rolling my own system.  The problem with a remote syslog system is the 1024 character limit, and a roll-my-own system is undesirable due to stability issues.  Ideally, I'd like to have a system that I can just fire off the log entry from the server and forget about it.  Does anyone know of any other options I have available?

Comment: What language/platform/framework is your app built on? Some environments have decent logging available with an add-on. Java has Log4J, for example.

Comment: It's a Win32 app set for Windows 2k and up, so not muc unless I can remotely log to another machine's event log which isn't desireable anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

syslog-ng via TCP works pretty well, but as you stated it is limited to more or less single line logs.

You might take a look at Splunk, it is expensive but it has log forward agents on each server that can handle almost any format.  The GUI is wonderful, and has some very powerful search and reporting tools.

Answer (score 2):

Edit - I fail at googling. The RFC does specify a 1024-byte max message size.

Syslog is the tried and true, to my mind. What are you referring to by this ? Doing some googling, I don't see any such limit in syslog.

> The problem with a remote syslog system is the 1024 character limit

Answer (score 0):

Splunk looked pretty good, but we couldn't justify the price compared to a roll-your-own, so I had to roll up a basic logging server using a UDP connection.  Fortunately, a 64k size limit gives me the ability to send 99%+ of my log messages through with just one UDP datagram.